# Python time.sleep() running into Floating Point exception

Tags: python, floating-point-exceptions

I am using the Python time.sleep() function in a GNURadio program. However, in spite of me having provided a floating point argument, the code runs into an unexpected Floating Point Exception. Please find the relevant code snippet below (please ignore the debugging "Hehe"'s :-)):

```
while not ack and timeout < 5: #FIXME: Hard-coded timeout interval
    print "Hehe5"   
    timeout+=1
    print "Hehe6"
    time.sleep(0.5)
    print "Hehe7"
    with lock:
        ack=recvd_prev_ack
    print "Hehe8"
```

This gives the following output:

```
Sent pktno=   0
Hehe
Hehe1
Hehe2
Hehe3
Hehe4
Hehe5
Hehe6
Floating point exception
```

So the point of error really is time.sleep(). Can someone please explain what could be going on here? My Python version is 2.7.1.

Thanks and Regards,
Dhrubo

Comment: Interesting... think you can post the actual error from console. I'm hoping it has some more detail, which would be useful

Comment: Your indentation is all wrong. Please fix it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What's going on here is your program is threaded, and the Floating point exception is happening in another thread (not where you think).

Comment: Thanks for the response. I have located the source of error. It was indeed due to a second running thread. :-)

Comment: I think you don't get a traceback since the error's not occurring in your main thread.  Maybe see here on how to get that other thread's traceback: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/875453/printing-daemonic-thread-exceptions-in-python